How to invert the color of an SVG (from Black contours on transparent background to White contours on transparent background)?
I am not a graphic designer or anything near it, just do some CSS.
I have this svg file:
https://www.svgrepo.com/show/533286/phone-call-alt-1.svg
I need its contours White instead of Black so I can make it more clear or accessible on top of a blue background.
How to invert the color of an SVG (from Black contours on transparent background to White contours on transparent background)?

Since it is a SVG (so, vector graphics), in the general case, not with Gimp (which is a raster editor) but with Inkscape, which is designed to edit SVG.
However, for such a simple file, a text editor is enough, you just need to  change the color on the stroke attributes (here to purple, because white-on-white would be confusing):



SVGrepro.com allows online adjustments of their files.
One could just go find the svg there and use the online tools to change colors and then click the "Export" button for a new, color changed, svg file.
svgrepo.com/svg/502792/phone-call?edit=true
Just change the #000000 value under the icon on the left to #ffffff and export it.
